# Is it possible to write every even permutation in $S_n$ as a square of some even permutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

In other words, consider $A_n$, the alternating group of the $n$-th symmetrical group $S_n$, is it true that 
$$A_n=\{a^2\mid a\in A_n\}$$?
I tested for $S_3$ and it seemed to hold. If it is true, it will be very helpful to me for solving another problem.

Comment: Not true for $n=4$; see $\left(12\right)\left(34\right)$ (in cycle notation).

Comment: What (I think) is true is that every even permutation is the square of some permutation in $S_n$. To prove this, it is enough to consider the case of an odd cycle and the case of a product of two disjoint even cycles; these cases are straightforward.

Comment: @darijgrinberg alright. Thanks! I just asked a silly question here :)

Comment: Darij has already answered your question, but I just wanted to note that $S_3$ (and $A_3$) are _very_ tiny groups to draw conclusions from because there are so few elements and so there's really no room for 'bad' behavior.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I don't think $(1,2)(3,4,5,6) \in A_6$ has a square root in $S_6$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks! This is exactly why I don't post my pseudo-answers as answers. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

darij is incorrect; it's not even possible to write every even permutation as a square of some permutation, even or odd! As an exercise, show that a permutation has a square root (in $S_n$) iff it has an even number of cycles of each even length. (Derek Holt's example in the comments is the smallest example where a permutation has cycles of two different even lengths.)

Comment: +1 for the solution, although I don't like the opening statement a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking whether the map $A_n \rightarrow A_n$ defined by $a \mapsto a^2$ is surjective. Since $A_n$ is a finite set that's the same asking whether the map is bijective. This is not true when $n \geq 4$, because then the map is not injective: for example, you can find $a \neq 1$ with $a^2 = 1$.